# Open/close navbar

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4, toggle

Webpage: http://www.webbuilders.biz/test-durrani/index.html

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mitchellbarron10/pen/EqZjQj

The JavaScript is in the html code.

I need help getting the navbar (on the top right of the page) to be closed when the page is loaded. It needs to open when clicked on, and close when the X is clicked (in the top right of the navbar)

I tried using two different buttons, one for openbtn and one for closebtn

```
<div id="main">
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button> 
<ul id="menuicons">
  <a href="../html-link.htm"><img src="images/noun_Login_801390.png" width="82" height="86" title="White flower" alt="Flower"></a>
  <a href="../html-link.htm"><img src="images/noun_Shopping Cart_17861.png" width="82" height="86" title="White flower" alt="Flower"></a>
 </ul>
</div>
<script>
script type="text/javascript">/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
function openNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
 function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
 }    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
 function openNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `onload="myfunction()"` event which allows you to call a function when the page is first loaded, so if you were to add the `closeNav()` function to the `onload` event, it would look something like this: `<body onload="closeNav()"`.

By adding `<body onload="closeNav()">` to your current codepen it does not show the menu on the right when the page is first loaded, then by clicking on another button you just have to add the `onClick="openNav()"` event to something of your choice to open the navbar.